# changing text color of an xamdatagrid

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I found out how to change the text color from a xamdatagrid cell. Right now I'm doing it like this:

 rec.FieldLayout.Fields["Message Category"].Settings.CellValuePresenterStyleSelector = colors;

rec is a datarecord. and colors is a  StyleSelector

 
is there anyway I can do this but instead of just changing one cell I can change the entire row?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a property in the ViewModel which based on the conditions decides whether to set the foreground color for a row.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRowValid}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</DataTrigger>
```